# Rolling 3 dice n number of times and calculating pair and triplet probability in C

Tags: c

Trying to write a C program that simulates 1000 throws of three dice and calculates the probability of 2 or 3 numbers appearing on all 3 dice at once. This is my code and I've been scratching my head for days now and can't figure out what's wrong... Theoretically it should work, but the numbers being printed out are usually around 3000 for the pairs and -(huge number) for the triplets.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i,coppia,tris,d1,d2,d3;
    float probCoppia, probTris;

    printf(" Rolling 3 dice 1000 times...\n");

    for(i=1; i<=1000; i++){
        int d1=rand()%6+1;
        int d2=rand()%6+1;
        int d3=rand()%6+1;

        if(d1==d2 || d1==d3 || d2==d3){
            coppia++;
        }
        else if(d1==d2 && d1==d3){
            tris++;
        }
    }

    probCoppia=coppia*0.1;
    probTris=tris*0.1;
    printf("Pair probability: %f\nTriplet probability: %f",probCoppia,probTris);

}
```

Comment: properly initialize accumulators `coppia = 0;`, `tris = 0;` before the loop.

Comment: BTW, your `if (d1==d2 || d1==d3 || d2==d3) { coppia++; } else if (di == d2 && d1 == d3) { /* never executes*/ }`

Comment: @Raphaël Or `%f` should be `%f%%`

Comment: Do you want a set like `3 3 3` to be counted only for `tris` or both for `tris` and `coppia`? Pay attention to your `if`s and `else`s

Comment: @500-InternalServerError  Generates percent by `* 100.0 / NTIMES` where NTIMES = 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must initialize the counters before the loop.
Otherwise, you will invoke *undefined behavior* by using values of uninitialized non-static local variables, which are indeterminate.

In other words, the line

```
int i,coppia,tris,d1,d2,d3;
```

should be

```
int i,coppia=0,tris=0,d1,d2,d3;
```

Also note that when `d1==d2 && d1==d3`, `d1==d2 || d1==d3 || d2==d3` will always be true, so `tris++;` will never be executed. (as @pmg says)
Threfore, the `if` statements should be swapped like this if you don't want to treat triplets as pairs:

```
if(d1==d2 && d1==d3){
    tris++;
}
else if(d1==d2 || d1==d3 || d2==d3){
    coppia++;
}
```

or remove the `else` like this if you want to treat triplets as pairs:

```
if(d1==d2 || d1==d3 || d2==d3){
    coppia++;
}
if(d1==d2 && d1==d3){
    tris++;
}
```

Comment: @pmg Thanks for having me notice the another possibility.

Comment: thank you very much, appears i am still an idiot... this is like my main mistake when using counters, for some reason i still forget this.

Comment: @acryllect: always compile with the most warnings you can (with gcc, try at least `gcc -Wall -Wextra ...`) and **mind the warnings**

Comment: @MikeCAT You missed that OP is redeclaring d1, d2 and d3